# Cassandra: no viable alternative at input 'IF'

Tags: cassandra, cql

This query:

`UPDATE jdtestbysentence."sparseSupplement" SET uuid = 2b22da9c-58a6-11e8-ae82-2d3e941502e8 WHERE a_uid = "1849" IF EXISTS`

gives this error:

> no viable alternative at input 'IF' (...=
>   2b22da9c-58a6-11e8-ae82-2d3e941502e8 WHERE a_uid = ["184]9" IF...)

I am fairly new to Cassandra.
Can someone advise?

Comment: It’s mostly comes when you have some syntax error so please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE jdtestbysentence."sparseSupplement"
SET uuid = 2b22da9c-58a6-11e8-ae82-2d3e941502e8 WHERE a_uid = "1849" IF EXISTS
```

Ok, so I created your table on my local like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "sparseSupplement" (uuid UUID, a_uid TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
```

I ran your CQL UPDATE, and sure enough I got the same error message.  Essentially, there is some confusion around the use of quotes here.  Double quotes are only to be used when enforcing case on a table or column name.  When setting or checking the value of a TEXT (`a_uid`) you should use single quotes around 1849:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> UPDATE "sparseSupplement"
    SET uuid = 2b22da9c-58a6-11e8-ae82-2d3e941502e8
    WHERE a_uid = '1849' IF EXISTS;

 [applied]
-----------
     False
```

Pro-tip: Also, I would caution you against using double-quotes like that.  Unless you absolutely need it to match case to a Java class, it's just going to make it more difficult to work with that table.  Kind of like it did here.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried your query with some modification in my test environment and it worked.

```
UPDATE jdtestbysentence."sparseSupplement" SET uuid = 2b22da9c-58a6-11e8-ae82-2d3e941502e8 WHERE a_uid = '1849' IF EXISTS
```